# Wizard orientation in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PF 5.0 and I wonder whether there is a possibility to have the Wizard component work like the tabView component : I would like to have the orientation set to "left".

Is a feature like this planned or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be possible with some CSS skills. Have a look at the relevant style classes provided in the PrimeFaces 5.0 documentation:

- .ui-wizard
- .ui-wizard-content
- .ui-wizard-step-titles
- .ui-wizard-step-title
- .ui-wizard-navbar
- .ui-wizard-nav-next
- .ui-wizard-nav-back

You can download the pdf [here](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf)

I hope this helps you. Good luck and tell me whether you were succesfull.